# Changing keyboard shortcuts for magnifier in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, magnifier

How can I change keyboard shortcuts for in-built magnifier?

Comment: Which version of Windows? Do you want to change all of the shortcuts, or just one specifically?

Comment: I want to change only one.

Comment: So is it possible to change Windows Keyboard Shortcuts trough the registry? I'm running Win10x64